# Get data by Popularity/Rating using Elasticsearcch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to do a get request using elasticsearch which needs to get the data with respect to its Popularity/ rating. So I followed this [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/search-rank-eval.html)
. I set the rating of my item by using the below one,

```html
#1 http://localhost:9200/cars/car/_rank_eval
    above is the Api which is used to create _rank_eval using postman ,

    Below is my Body content ,

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "horsepower",
      "request": {
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "horsepower": "68"
          }
        }
      },
      "ratings": [
        {
          "_index": "cars",
          "_id": "25",
          "rating": 10
        },
        {
          "_index": "cars",
          "_id": "119",
          "rating": 1
        },
        {
          "_index": "cars",
          "_id": "52",
          "rating": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metric": {
      "precision": {
        "relevant_rating_threshold": 1,
        "ignore_unlabeled": false
      }
   }
}
```

Steps i did so far ,
1 . Created database with dumb data's in MySql
2 . Transferred my db data's to ElasticSearch using loadstash
3 . Set some rating's to my data

so what are all the next steps , did i miss anything .. I need some clarification/help on this .